# I am making Unit test for account service which is depended on User Manager and Sign Manager, But Can't Get Application User

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, moq

I Mocked User manager, SignIn manager and Account Repository but still cannot get Application User to add the claim. Here Is my Account Service Code and Constructor

```
IAccountRepository _accountRepo;

        public AccountService(IAccountRepository accountRepo)
        {
            _accountRepo = accountRepo;
      }



        public Task<bool> AddClaim(ApplicationUser user, Claim claim)
        {
            return _accountRepo.AddClaim(user, claim);
        }
```

Here is my AccountRepository Code and Constructor.

```
ApplicationDbContext _context;
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _Hcontext;
        public AccountRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
                                UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
                                IHttpContextAccessor Hcontext)
        {
            _context = context;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _Hcontext = Hcontext;
        }
```

```
public async Task<bool> AddClaim(ApplicationUser user, Claim claim)
        {
            var result=await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);
            if (result.Succeeded)
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }
        public Guid GetCurrentUserId()
        {
            return Guid.Parse(_Hcontext.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
        }
        public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = _Hcontext.HttpContext.User;
            return await _userManager.GetUserAsync(claimsPrincipal);
        }
```

and here is my Unit test Setups and one test which give me always Null in form of application User.

```
`[SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
             .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDbOR247")
             .Options;
            context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
            ApplicationUser userNew = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Cvr = 12345678,
                IsBusiness = true,
                CustomerNumber = 0,
                Type = 0
            };
            userNew.IsBusiness = true;
            userNew.Email = "I@gmail.com";
            userNew.UserName = "Ikram@123";
            userNew.Id = userId.ToString();
            List<ApplicationUser> _users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            _users.Add(userNew);
            
            var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
           
            var _userManager = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(mockUserStore.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            _userManager.Setup(x => x.DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);
            _userManager.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(userNew, "Abcd-1234")).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);
            _userManager.Setup(x => x.UpdateAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);



            var _signInManager = new Mock<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>(_userManager.Object, Mock.Of<IHttpContextAccessor>(), Mock.Of<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>>(), null, null, null, null);
            var roleStore = new Mock<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
            var _roleManager= new Mock<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>(
                         roleStore.Object, null, null, null, null);
            var mockHttpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            mockHttpContextAccessor.Setup(o => o.HttpContext.User).Returns(It.IsAny<ClaimsPrincipal>());
            //_accountRepository = new AccountRepository(context,_signInManager.Object,_userManager.Object,_roleManager.Object,mockHttpContextAccessor.Object);

            _accountRepository = new Mock<AccountRepository>(context, _signInManager.Object, _userManager.Object, _roleManager.Object, mockHttpContextAccessor.Object);
            //mockUserStore.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(userNew, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()).Result).Returns(It.IsAny<IdentityResult>);

            var data = context.AppUsers.ToList();
            if(data.Count==0)
            {
                AddSampleDataIntoDatabase();
            }
            var abc = context.Users.ToList();
            var list=_accountRepository.Object.GetUsers();
            //auto mapper configuration
            var mockMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new ApplicationMapper());
            });
            var mapper = mockMapper.CreateMapper();
            accountService = new AccountService(_accountRepository.Object);
        }

[Test]
        public async Task AddClaim_UserNotNull_ReturnTrue()
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Cvr = 12345678,
                IsBusiness = true,
                CustomerNumber = 0,
                Type = 0
            };
            var user1 = accountService.GetUsers();
            var claim = AllClaims[0];
            //Act
            var result = await accountService.AddClaim(user, claim);
            //Assert
            Assert.That(result, Is.True);
        }`
```

I tried UserManager setup by create User but and then I can get that user in form of application user and test the add claim test, but I think it's not creating the user.

Comment: `tried UserManager setup by create User but and then I can get that user in form of application user and test the add claim test, but I think it's not creating the user.` It looks like you didn't add user into db in `AddClaim_UserNotNull_ReturnTrue()`.

Comment: I Setup userManager by creating User but It was not creating User Now I am Creating User through context and then I get it Through accountService.GetUsers(it gives me one Aplication User)

Comment: with That code _userManager.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(userNew)).Returns(It.IsAny<Task<IdentityResult>>);